# How do I rewrite a URL so that the rewrite can be typed into the URL bar?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following page: `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact` and I'd like to rewrite it so that it shows up as: `www.domain.com/contact`, but there's more...

What's important, is that when someone types in `www.domain.com/contact`, it redirects them to `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact`, which in turn, is rewritten as `www.domain.com/contact`.

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

**Edit:** To clarify

I want users to be able to enter `www.domain.com/contact` and be redirected to `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact`.

However once redirected, I'd like a **purely aesthetic rewrite** so that `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact` shows up as `www.domain.com/contact` (the same as what they typed in.)

Is this possible?

**Edit:** My .htaccess file currently...

```
Options +FollowSymlinks

# Prevent Directoy listing 
Options -Indexes

# Prevent Direct Access to files
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini)">
 Order deny,allow
 Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# SEO URL Settings
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=common/home$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !^POST$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.domain.com/? [R=301,L]


### Additional Settings that may need to be enabled for some servers 
### Uncomment the commands by removing the # sign in front of it.
### If you get an "Internal Server Error 500" after enabling, then restore the # as this means your host 

doesn't allow that.

# 1. If your cart only allows you to add one item at a time, it is possible register_globals is on. This 

may work to disable it:
# php_flag register_globals off
```

Comment: What you're describing would create an infinite redirect...
 
redirect contact -> index.php?route=information/contact
redirect index.php?route=information/contect -> contact

Are you sure this is what you're trying to do?

Comment: @David - I only want the `index.php?route=information/contact` to be rewritten (not redirected)...just purely aesthetic--but the key is that people need to be able to type in the aesthetic URL, and have that redirect to the real URL...which will be (only in appearance) the same as the aesthetic URL.

Comment: But the aesthetic URL is going to have to be rewritten anyway. Why not just use the functional URL to run the script?

Comment: @Ignacio - pardon my ignorance, but I'm seeking help because I have no idea how to do this--so what you're suggesting has flown right over my head. If what I'm trying to achieve is clear, can you post a solution for me to try?

Comment: Why aren't you using a framework? Django (Python) has pretty urls, Rails (Ruby) also have them, Recess (PHP) have them so you can pick a framework in a language of your choice. You're dealing with a solved problem here.

Comment: @the_drow I'm using Opencart, an opensource e-commerce platform. It has pretty URLS built in for the categories and products, but my client has a link to `domain.com/warranty` printed on thousands of product inserts... so I need to take the warranty page I've built (the 'route=information/contact' page,) and have it accessible via typing in `domain.com/warranty` ...I'd just love to keep the URL showing the same thing they typed in, not just a complete redirect to the actual (and far less semantic) information/contact url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these rules in your .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s/+index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=information [NC]
RewriteRule . /warranty? [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteRule ^warranty$ /index.php?route=information/contact [L,NC]
```

`L` will make sure that user's URL in browser doesn't change and redirection happens **internally**.

Comment: @anubhava - It looks like you're truncating the URL... the above were just examples, the actual rewrite needs to point `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact` to `www.domain.com/warranty` ...since the contact form is actually for registering a product warranty--how would the code in your example change for this? I didn't think about the confusion/similarity of "contact" and "information/contact."

Comment: Edited the answer above to reflect `/index.php?route=information/contact` to `/warranty`. Since your original URI here has no reference to target URI `/warranty` therefore for each rule like that you will have to add 1 RewriteRule line as in my answer.

Comment: @anubhava - Hmm, I popped that code in there... typed in `www.domain.com/warranty` and nothing happened. I typed in `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact` manually, and yet the URL bar didn't change. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Edited my answer to make sure rule works both ways, Please try again.

Comment: @Anubhava - Thank you for your help! Can you take a look at the .htaccess file above--to see if anything is conflicting? the rewrite appears to be working, but when I goto `www.domain.com/warranty` I get a 404. If I goto `index.php?route=information/contact` it redirects, and I get the same 404... maybe it's a conflict with the platform?

Comment: Added one more correction, please try again. Also in your .htaccess file: this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]` should be `RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]`

Comment: @anubhava - Hmm, I made the correction you suggested and tried the new warranty rewrite code--but it's still serving up a 404. It appears to be redirecting to /warranty (which doesn't exist) instead of just changing the display of the URL. I hate to keep bothering you, as I do appreciate your help, but I'm at loss....

Comment: Yes that's what I thought you wanted i.e. `/index.php?route=information/contact` to change to `/warranty` in the browser. If not then pls tell me one more time.

Comment: @anubhaba - I need the user to type in `/warranty` and be taken to `/index.php?route=information/contact` --and ideally, the URL bar should stay showing `/warranty` even though technically the real page being served up is `/index.php?route=information/contact`

Comment: I think I understood your requirement now :) Just updated my answer, please test and let me know.

Comment: @anubhava - Man I earnestly appreciate your help, but it still doesn't seem to work--`index.php?route=information/contact` is redirecting to `/warranty`... but `/warranty` doesn't exist, so it serves a 404 error. I need the opposite, I need `/warranty` to redirect to `/index.php?route=information/contact` --that's the most important. Now, if we can get the URL to SHOW (not redirect) `/warranty` after the redirect (so it still looks like you typed in /warranty) that'd be amazing. Is there anything more I can do to help troubleshoot this? I'm just itching to hit the green check mark :)

Comment: Mate, I tested above rules on today Linux, Mac and XAMPP installation before editing. Just copy/paste above code **as is** into your .htaccess file. Last line above `RewriteRule ^warranty$ /index.php?route=information/contact [L,NC]` takes care of internally redirecting `/warranty` to `/index.php?route=information/contact`. So as long as you have `/index.php` available it should work. Would you post your .htaccess and apache's relevant access & error logs as well for debugging.

Comment: @anubhava - Amazing!!!! I found that my other .htaccess rules were conflicting, so I put your rules first (I had previously put them at the bottom) and now it works great!! Hopefully the other stuff doesn't break, but I've marked this as the correct answer--thank you 1000 times anubhava!

Comment: My pleasure, glad that it worked out for you. Hopefully these rules will not step over each other.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is extremely unclear, and I suspect that inexperience is to blame.

With the following rule:

```
RewriteRule /?(.*) index.php?route=information/$1
```

the location bar will read "/contact" but index.php will be invoked via an internal rewrite.

With a small modification:

```
RewriteRule /?(.*) index.php?route=information/$1 [R]
```

the location bar will read "/index.php?route=information/contact" and index.php will be invoked, after the redirect.

As always, the rule should follow the appropriate `RewriteCond` so as to avoid rewriting if an actual file is requested.

Comment: @Ignacio - See my comment on Anubhava's answer. My apologies for the confusion--I didn't think people would attempt to truncate the URL to only show 'contact;' ideally `www.domain.com/whatever-I-pick` would point to `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact` while leaving the URL bar showing `www.domain.com/whatever-I-pick`.

Comment: So then use the former rule, replacing the LHS as appropriate.

Comment: would the condition look like this? `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^route=information/contact$` Also, what is LHS? I tried using the first line of code you supplied, and it killed my CSS (and no URL changes/redirects happened.)

Comment: No. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f`

Comment: @Ignacio - Let me say first, that I appreciate your help. I've edited my original post with my current .htaccess file--I have done zero htaccess modifications--what you see are the mechanisms I was instructed to put in for URL rewriting within this installation of Opencart. As you can see the `www.domain.com/index.php?route=common/home` is setup to redirect to `www.domain.com`, and the other rule is for the product URL rewrites. I'm trying to get the page `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact` to be accessible by typing `www.domain.com/warranty` without the URL visibly changing.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can't make the address bar show a different address than the one that the page was loaded from.  If you want the user to see `www.domain.com/contact` in the address bar when viewing the page, you need to make the server actually return the page content (not a redirect) when that URL is requested.

I think you might be misunderstanding URL rewriting:  it's not for changing what the user sees in the address bar, it's for changing what the *server* sees when a request arrives from the user.  If you create a rewrite rule that changes `/foo` to `/bar`, then when the user types `/foo` in their browser, the server will treat it as a request for `/bar`.

What you want, I think, is that when the user types `www.domain.com/contact` in their browser, the server should treat it as a request for `www.domain.com/index.php?route=information/contact`, but the browser should still show the pretty URL that the user typed.  The way to do that is to simply rewrite `/contact` to `/index.php?route=information/contact` on the server.  No redirect is needed; the user simply requests the pretty URL, and the server handles the request based on the equivalent ugly one and sends back the resulting page.